# Need help loading dds textures in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

The model loads in blender with the proper textures applied, when I export it to obj + mtl I get the textures as .dds files and don't know how to apply them in threejs.
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

If the `MTL` file refers to `DDS` textures, you have to include `DDSLoader` into your project and then use the following code:

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.addHandler( /\.dds$/i, new DDSLoader() );

var mtlLoader = new MTLLoader( manager );
```

The official `OBJ/MTL` actually uses this approach to load the DDS texture for the character model.

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl

`three.js R112`